# Did anyone have a problem with CKEditor after 4.6.22 upgrade?

Tags: ckeditor

After updating my Civi installation from 4.6.x to 4.6.22, my CKEditor was broken (blank screen in edit window, all areas).

Answer (score 3):

After checking my js console, I found my justify plugin folder was missing:

../civicrm/packages/ckeditor/plugins/justify  <= folder missing

I downloaded the plugin from here: http://ckeditor.com/addon/justify

Expand the .zip in plugins folder, it will create the justify folder and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like that plugin is *not* missing in the latest 4.6. But it's incorporated into the build of CKEditor, not in a separate file. Maybe you just needed to clear your caches?

Comment: I have another site to upgrade, I'll try to recreate being a newbie :o as I should have checked that.  The fact that I couldn't find another reference made me wonder if it was just me...probably just me!  Thanks Coleman!